# Property of the solution of a second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a, b$ be two real numbers. If the function $x(t)$ is a solution of
$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}+ 2a\frac{dx}{dt}+ bx = 0$$
with $x(0) = x(1) = 0$, then show that $x(n) = 0$ for all $n \in\mathbb N$.

There is a hint given, which asks to show that $x(t+1)=cx(t)$, for some $c\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Yes but I want to solve using the hint, without using explicit formulae.

Answer (score 1):

If the solution is all zero, then you are done.

If not, then $x'(1)=cx'(0)$ defines $c$. Now consider $y(t)=x(t+1)-cx(t)$ and show that it is a solution of the ODE with $y(0)=y'(0)=0$. Conclude with $x(t+n)=c^nx(t)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $x(t+1)=cx(t)$ for some $c\in\mathbb R,$ which is useful because it follows immediately from the boundary conditions that $x(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N.$

This is because you have $x(0+1)=x(1)=cx(0)=0,x(2)=cx(1)=0,x(3)=cx(2)=0,....$ thus $x(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N.$

To show that $x(t+1)=cx(t)$ you have to show that it satisfies the boundary conditions at $t=0$ and $t=1$, which we have already done, and it also satisfies the ODE.

But since $x'(t+1)=cx'(t)$ and $x''(t+1)=cx''(t)$ substituting into the ODE we have:

$$\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}x(t+1)+2a\frac{d}{dt}x(t+1)+bx(t+1)$$
$$=cx''(t)+2acx'(t)+bcx(t)$$
$$=c\big(\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^2}+2a\frac{dx}{dt}+bx\big)=0$$

since we know that $x(t)$ is a solution of the ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Observe first that, if $x(t)$ is a solution of
$$
x''+ax'+bx=0, \quad a,b\in\mathbb R,
$$
then so is $y(t)=x(t+d)$, for all $d\in\mathbb R$.

Case I. If $x\equiv 0$, then there is nothing to prove.

Case II. If $x\not\equiv 0$, then $x'(0)\ne0$ and $x'(1)\ne 0$. Set
$$
y(t)=x(t+1)-\frac{x'(1)}{x'(0)}x(t)
$$
Clearly, $y$ satisfies the IVP
$$
x''+ax'+bx=0, \quad x(0)=x'(0)=0,
$$
and hence it is identically zero. Thus
$$
x(t+1)=\frac{x'(1)}{x'(0)}x(t), \quad \text{for all}\,\,\, t\in\mathbb R,
$$
and hence, for $c=\frac{x'(1)}{x'(0)}$,
$$
x(n)=c x(n-1)=c^2 x(n-2)=\cdots=c^{n}x(0)=0, \quad \text{for all $n\in\mathbb N$}.
$$